# React Native : Element type is invalid

Tags: react-native, syntax-error

Beginner in React Native, I dry on the following error message:
Error: Invalid element type: expected string (for inline components) or class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You probably forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you may have confused default and named imports.
Check the rendering method of `Todo`.
The answers obtained via Bing's AI do not help me.

---

Here is the app:

---

```
//App.js
import App from './src/components/App'
export default App

//src/components/App.js
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import TodoList from './TodoList';

export default function App() {
    const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState([
        { id: 1, label: 'Buy some milk' }, 
        { id: 2, label: 'Learn some React' } ]);
    const updateTodoLabel = (todoId, label) => {
        const todoIndex = todos.findIndex(t => t.id === todoId)
        const todosBefore = todos.slice(0, todoIndex) 
        const todosAfter = todos.slice(todoIndex + 1) 
        const newtodo = { ...todos[todoIndex], label } 
        setTodos([...todosBefore, newtodo, ...todosAfter])
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}> 
            <TodoList todos={todos} updateTodoLabel={updateTodoLabel}/> 
        </View> 
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        marginTop: 25,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
    }, 
});

//src/components/TodoList.js
import React from 'react' 
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native' 
import Todo from './Todo' 
 
const TodoList = ({ todos, updateTodoLabel }) => ( 
    <View style={styles.todoList}> 
        {todos.map(todo => ( 
        <Todo todo={todo} key={todo.id} updateTodoLabel={label => updateTodoLabel(todo.id, label)}/> 
        ))} 
    </View> 
)
 
const styles = StyleSheet.create({ 
    todoList: { 
    flex: 1, 
    alignItems: 'stretch' 
    } 
}) 

export default TodoList


//src/components/Todo.js
import React from 'react' 
import { Text, StyleSheet, Fragment, TextInput, Button, View } from 'react-native' 
 
const Todo = ({todo, updateTodoLabel}) => {
    const [editMode, setEditMode] = React.useState(false);  
    const [label, setLabel] = React.useState(todo.label); 

    //const label = todo.label

    const onEditPress = () => {
        setEditMode(true)
    }

    const onChange = (label) => {
        setLabel(label)
    }

    const onSavePress = (label) => {
        updateTodoLabel(label)
        setEditMode(false)
    }

    const onCancelPress = () => {
        setEditMode(false)
        setLabel(todo.label)
    }

    const renderViewMode = () => (
        <Fragment> 
            <Text style={styles.todoLabel}>{todo.label}</Text> 
                <Button title="Edit" onPress={onEditPress} /> 
            </Fragment> 
    )

    const renderEditMode = () => (
        <Fragment> 
            <TextInput 
                style={[styles.editInput, styles.todoLabel]} 
                value={label} 
                onChangeText={onChange} 
                autoFocus 
            /> 
            <Button title="Save" onPress={onSavePress} /> 
            <Button title="Cancel" onPress={onCancelPress} /> 
        </Fragment> 
    )

    return (
        <View style={styles.todo}>
            {editMode ? renderEditMode() : renderViewMode() }  
        </View>
    ) 
} 

const styles = StyleSheet.create({ 
   todo: { 
       padding: 10, 
       borderTopWidth: 1, 
       borderStyle: 'solid', 
       borderColor: 'lightgray' 
   },
   todoLabel: { 
      fontSize: 18, 
      padding: 10, 
      flex: 1 
   },
}) 

export default Todo
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

I tried to understand the error message, trying to use JSInspector, but as a problem rarely comes alone, I have a vscode setting problem to launch the browser... So I stuck...

Comment: Everything looks good to me. Might be metro issue. 1: Try to reset the cache of metro, delete the app and try reinstalling again. 2: Check if your paths of imports are correct. 3. Switch to Named exports. I had the same issue as you and switching to named exports was the only thing that helped.

Comment: Thank you. I did that, combined with the other suggested solution to replace <Fragment>...</Fragment> by <>...</> and it is ok now.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `<Fragment></Fragment>`, use the short form `<></>`
Here is an [example](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/fragments-cause-missing-export)

```js
import React from 'react' 
import { Text, StyleSheet, Fragment, TextInput, Button, View } from 'react-native' 
 
const Todo = ({todo, updateTodoLabel}) => {
    const [editMode, setEditMode] = React.useState(false);  
    const [label, setLabel] = React.useState(todo.label); 

    //const label = todo.label

    const onEditPress = () => {
        setEditMode(true)
    }

    const onChange = (label) => {
        setLabel(label)
    }

    const onSavePress = (label) => {
        updateTodoLabel(label)
        setEditMode(false)
    }

    const onCancelPress = () => {
        setEditMode(false)
        setLabel(todo.label)
    }

    const renderViewMode = () => (
        <> 
            <Text style={styles.todoLabel}>{todo.label}</Text> 
            <Button title="Edit" onPress={onEditPress} /> 
        </> 
    )

    const renderEditMode = () => (
        <> 
            <TextInput 
                style={[styles.editInput, styles.todoLabel]} 
                value={label} 
                onChangeText={onChange} 
                autoFocus 
            /> 
            <Button title="Save" onPress={onSavePress} /> 
            <Button title="Cancel" onPress={onCancelPress} /> 
        </> 
    )

    return (
        <View style={styles.todo}>
            {editMode ? renderEditMode() : renderViewMode() }  
        </View>
    ) 
} 

const styles = StyleSheet.create({ 
   todo: { 
       padding: 10, 
       borderTopWidth: 1, 
       borderStyle: 'solid', 
       borderColor: 'lightgray' 
   },
   todoLabel: { 
      fontSize: 18, 
      padding: 10, 
      flex: 1 
   },
}) 

export default Todo
```

Comment: Thank you. It sounded weird, but it works !